# Angular how to extend component with dynamic service class

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a base component and specify service that we need to use:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-base',
    templateUrl: './base.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./base.component.scss']
})
export class BaseComponent<T extends BaseService> implements OnInit {
     service: T;
     ngOnInit(): void {
         this.service = this.injector.get(this.service);

         this.service.commonMethod();
     }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-base',
    templateUrl: './base.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./base.component.scss']
})
export class MyBaseComponent extends BaseComponent<MyService> implements OnInit {

    service = MyService;
}
```

But following code raising an error that `BaseService` have missing properties and methods from `MyService`.

```
class MyService extends BaseService
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to import the service via a constructor you do not need to extend the base service like you are doing.

```
constructor(private yourservice:YourImportedService){}
```

Comment: No, I have like 7 services that a very similar and I want to have 7 components that will have similar functionality, but with ability to customize each one. That's why I want to pass service dynamically and I can't do something like:
`public companyService: BuilderOrganizationService | RaterOrganizationService,` in constructor